# Update with float type in MySQL

Tags: mysql, floating-point

I'm trying to do a simple update query in MySQL but it doesn't work:

```
UPDATE dimensions
SET is_active = 1
WHERE eco_tax = 19.2;
```

eco_tax is a FLOAT type column and it seems that here is the problem, because when I try updating with an INT column it works.

So what cand I do to use a float in column in my where syntax in MySQL?

Comment: What's exactly the behavior you get?

Comment: 0 rows affected even if I have some columns containing 19.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I always encounter issues when i want to do `WHERE`s in databases, and it is most likely a issue with floating point math. I know that doubles work the same way, but for some odd reason, it always works with using doubles. Therefore, my suggestion to you is to change the datatype to double instead.

Answer (score 3):

Use `double` instead of `float`. It seems there has a bug of mySql. See the following link for more information.

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=14268

Answer (score 1):

The root of this problem is that some numbers cannot be represented exactly in floating point. You could try something like the following (unfortunately, I don't have access to a MySQL instance to hand to try this myself):

```
UPDATE dimensions
SET is_active = 1
WHERE ABS(eco_tax - 19.2) < 1E-08;
```

In other words, update if the difference between the two values is negligible.

Answer (score 1):

try to alter the column to `DECIMAL(x,y)`. 
I had the same issue and I discovered it happens only on the rows when a floating value is used in the where clause; I changed the column type from `FLOAT` to `DECIMAL(5,2)` (of course choose your scale and precision) and... no more problems!.

Comment: Great answer -- any time you need to represent a floating point value with an exact number of decimal places, the `DECIMAL` type is going to work better than `float` or `double`.  It can represent all values correctly and is probably faster.